# microsoft graph filter assigned role

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In Azure Active Directory I created an app, in the manifest file I've update the `appRoles` with the following value:

```
  "appRoles": [
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "displayName": "Client manager",
  "id": "bf77e391-0bbf-4e33-854b-a384a5ac0630",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "Client manager can manage all client actions.",
  "value": "ClientManager"
}]
```

I updated my user so that my assigned role is no longer `Default Access` but is `Client manager`

With Graph api I'm trying to retrieve this assigned role. 
I tried this uri but for some reason it will not return my role(s).
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/appRoleAssignments?$filter=resourceId eq 04dcaab1-7219-4689-8510-4672e957ac11$select=appRoleId`
But the response is:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Invalid filter clause",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "ce3cb456-956b-41c5-84a2-cdcdfe1ac3c5",
        "date": "2018-11-05T20:54:08"
    }
}
```

}

I could create a workaround requesting all my roles, for all my applications  but this is something I would like to avoid. This would end up with the following uri: 
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/appRoleAssignments?$select=resourceId,appRoleId`

and results in this json, where I need to filter out my applicationid.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#appRoleAssignments(resourceId,appRoleId)",
"value": [
    {
        "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "resourceId": "667cc3aa-00b9-4526-bde5-b81312ed5afb"
    },
    {
        "appRoleId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "resourceId": "64b92ac1-4a56-478c-8774-5c584fb200e5"
    },
    {
        "appRoleId": "bf77e391-0bbf-4e33-854b-a384a5ac0630",
        "resourceId": "04dcaab1-7219-4689-8510-4672e957ac11"
    }
]
```

}

I tried several solutions proposed on StackOverflow already but for some reason, all the `eq` filters don't work. I'm testing my query with the [Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). My desired result should be something like this:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#appRoleAssignments(appRoleId)",
"value": [
    {
        "appRoleId": "bf77e391-0bbf-4e33-854b-a384a5ac0630"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: _"it will not return my role(s)"_: What does it return?

Comment: I've added my current result and my desired endresult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not support to filter `resourceId` with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/appRoleAssignments`.

As mentioned in the [doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters):

> Not all parameters are supported across all Microsoft Graph APIs, and support might differ significantly between the `v1.0` and `beta` endpoints.

Also, if we filter the `id` with `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/appRoleAssignments?$filter=id eq 'xxxxxxx'`, it will work fine. So I think the format of the query should be correct, the only possibility is it is not supported as mentioned in the doc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought that was happening. My workaround will be used then.